# Redirect all extensions to homepage

Tags: redirect

I just changed the software language of my site, so I would like to 301 redirect any URL ending with .cfm to my homepage, Using `htaccess`

I looked around but couldn't find the answer.  I found how to change the extensions to another one but not how to redirect them all to one URL.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem here? You just need a single rule for this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.cfm$ / [L,R]
```

Obviously the rewriting module must be activated and granted inside `.htaccess` style files and consideration of such files must be enabled itself.

As a general rule of thumb: *if possible* you should prefer to place such rules inside the server configuration, not inside the document tree. That is because these `.htaccess` stile files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and really slow the server down.